# Randomly select from vector and assign to other variables without replacement

Tags: r

I have an object with 37 elements.

I want to randomly select from the object different number of elements and assign them to different objects without replacement. How can I do that?

```
vars <- c("a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5", "f6", "g7", "h8", "i9", "j10", "k11", "l12", "m13", "n14", "o15", 
"p16", "q17", "r18", "s19", "t20", "u21", "v22", "w23", "x24", "y25", "z26", "a27", "b28", "c29", "d30", 
"e31", "f32", "g33", "h34", "i35", "j36", "k37")

Group1 = 4 elements randomly selected from vars

Group2 = 5 elements randomly selected from vars

Group3 = 6 elements randomly selected from vars

Group4 = 9 elements randomly selected from vars

Group5 = 6 elements randomly selected from vars

Group6 = 7 elements randomly selected from vars
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
split(vars, sample(rep(paste0("Group", 1:6), c(4, 5, 6, 9, 6, 7))))

$Group1
[1] "f6"  "i9"  "b28" "d30"

$Group2
[1] "c3"  "d4"  "j10" "p16" "r18"

$Group3
[1] "h8"  "k11" "m13" "s19" "w23" "k37"

$Group4
[1] "e5"  "g7"  "u21" "z26" "a27" "c29" "e31" "i35" "j36"

$Group5
[1] "l12" "q17" "t20" "v22" "f32" "h34"

$Group6
[1] "a1"  "b2"  "n14" "o15" "x24" "y25" "g33"
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `sample` should do it.

```
Group1<-sample(vars,4)
Group2<-sample(vars,5)
```

Just type in the number of elements you want to be sampled and it will select them.
Fair note to add is that it won't be truly random but pseudo-random depending upon a pre-generated seed. If you set the seed for rng then you can reproduce the random samples every time.
For eg, `set.seed(341); sample(vars, 6)`. You may not need to set the seed in which case you will be able to sample different elements every time